# How to implement a Java crawler to crawl for PDF-file links?

Tags: java, web-crawler

Task details: Java web PDF Crawler 
Tool: Eclipse

I wanted to get a .pdf link as output. How to get that in java? 
Below mentioned should comes as output after crawling http://namastenepal.de. 
- http://namastenepal.de/menu_namaste_nepal_chemnitz_vegan_vegetarisch.pdf

From below mentioned it gives all html links(href): 
http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-simple-web-crawler-in-java/
As same like this I want to get output of files.

Kindly give me suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code that produces the links...

Comment: The codes which is mentioned in this.                                                                          http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-simple-web-crawler-in-java/  This gives only links. Not .pdf links.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crawler4j` (see https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j) and adjust the `shouldVisit(...)` method and `visit(...)` in `WebCrawler.class` for your use-case accordingly.

For your given example only, it would be something like:

```
 @Override
 public boolean shouldVisit(Page referringPage, WebURL url) {
     String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
     //only visit pages from namastenepal.de
     return href.startsWith("http://namastenepal.de");
 }
```

and

```
 @Override
 public void visit(Page page) {
     String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();

     //only process urls ending with .pdf after visting them...
     if (url.endsWith(".pdf") {
         //do something
     }
}
```

Note, that you cannot only include `.pdf` in `shouldVisit(...)` as you need to enable the crawler to traverse the given website to find `.pdf` links. For this reason, it needs to allow non `.pdf` links.